# Add LinearLayout before ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have a scrollview, but I want a linear layout with 3 buttons that stay on top when scrolling. So it should function kind of like navigation bar that sticks to the top.
Current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="32">
    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `ScrollView` inside a vertical `LinearLayout`, and have those three buttons added above the `ScrollView`.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
  <YourButtonsHere/>
  <ScrollView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in this way, your 3 buttons while be piling up. then you ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, but the easiest one is to have a vertical LinearLayout as the parent. You then put the buttons in a horizontal linearlayout, so that they are on the top and act as a 'bar'.
Then you only need to add the scrollview.
That way the user can scroll the scrollview and the 3 buttons stay on top of the scroll view.

```
<!-- vertical linear layout as parent -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        
    <!-- Place buttons in a horizontal linearlayout, so that you have a bar on the 
     top-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            
        <!-- buttons width=0 + same layout_weight, that way the width of the 
         linear layout is equally distributed between the 3 buttons--> 
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height=""
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height=""
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- your scroll view here-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width=""
        android:layout_height="">
            
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

XML:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.sharedcode.widgets.CustomButton
            style="@style/FlatButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_6" />

        <com.sharedcode.widgets.CustomButton
            style="@style/FlatButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_6" />

        <com.sharedcode.widgets.CustomButton
            style="@style/FlatButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn3"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_6" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        //in your case this is GridView
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
            android:id="@+id/gridRoot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:columnCount="2"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:rowCount="32"
            app:spanCount="2"
            tools:listitem="@layout/row_exam" />
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```